# Failed gitpoller on bitbucket using only_tags=True

Tags: bitbucket, buildbot

I set my buildbot to do auto deployment each time there's new tag from my
git repo on bitbucket
Following that I've wrote in master.cfg for gitpoller

```
c['change_source'].extend(changes.GitPoller(
    source_root + name + '.git', workdir=work_dir + name,
    only_tags=True,
    pollinterval=18 + i*60) for i, name in enumerate(projects))
```

**I've declare vars work_dir, name and projects on top of my master.cfg

When I look into my twistd.log, got following error invalid refspec when
buildbot trying to pull tag

```
['https://buildbot:password@bitbucket.org/bitbucket/project.git',
'+refs/tags/v0.1:refs/buildbot/https%3A%2F%2Fbuildbot%3password%
40bitbucket.org%2Fbitbucket%2Fproject.git/refs/tags/v0.1',
'+refs/tags/v0.1^{}:refs/buildbot/https%3A%2F%2Fbuildbot%3password%
40bitbucket.org%2Fbitbucket%2Fproject.git/refs/tags/v0.1^{}',
'+refs/tags/v0.2:refs/buildbot/https%3A%2F%2Fbuildbot%3password%
40bitbucket.org%2Fbitbucket%2Fproject.git/refs/tags/v0.2',
'+refs/tags/v0.2^{}:refs/buildbot/https%3A%2F%2Fbuildbot%3password%
40bitbucket.org%2Fbitbucket%2Fproject.git/refs/tags/v0.2^{}'] in
/src/88/gitpoller/project on repourl
https://buildbot:password@bitbucket.org/bitbucket/project.git failed with
exit code 128: fatal: Invalid refspec
'+refs/tags/v0.1^{}:refs/buildbot/https%3A%2F%2Fbuildbot%3password%
40bitbucket.org%2Fbitbucket%2Fproject.git/refs/tags/v0.1^{}
```

How can I make buildbot work to listen for new push tag on my repo?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The bug seems to be fixed in 1.1.1 with [fce8e858](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/commit/fce8e858b2f070525a9f2ac86306eb5f6fe729e8)